# How to access an element in array of ints via x86 assembly

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, x86

How to access an element in array of ints via x86 assembly?
My current code shows what I am trying to do:

```
int arr[3]{0,6,8};

__asm
{
   mov eax, [arr+1*4] // access value "6" in the array and put it in eax
}
```

eax shows a "0F5CA9A1" instead of 6 as needed

Comment: What is the question? If it's not working, you may want to add what goes wrong.

Comment: What's your compiler?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly on VS 2013:

```
int array[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
int idx0, idx1, idx2;

__asm {
    mov eax, [array + 0 * 4]
    mov idx0, eax
    mov eax, [array + 1 * 4]
    mov idx1, eax
    mov eax, [array + 2 * 4]
    mov idx2, eax
}

printf("%d %d %d\n", idx0, idx1, idx2);
```

**Outputs:**

```
10 20 30
```